# Filenames change when RSYNC to NAS with CIFS or NFS

Tags: rsync, truenas

I have noticed that after a RSYNC to a Truenas core 13 NAS with either a nfs or cifs mounted folder, file names will change.  Source device Kubuntu 22.04
example:   Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End (2007).m4v  will become PKOF8Y~2.M4V

I understand that :  or ()  may be a restricted char, however is there a way to get around this?   I also have a RSYNC to a ext4 mounted internal drive, and the files names remain unchanged.

I have tried setting the cifs to iocharset=utf8, but I did not see any change.

What I don't understand is this a result of the mount method or on the end of Truenas?

Any direction to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

It seems that my thoughts I was mounted with NFS was not accurate.  Once I was able to properly mounted the NAS with NFS, I was able to RSYNC and maintain the desired file name.  My issue was with the permissions on the NAS side.